# Java self expiring map/cache with minimum retention time

Tags: java, caching, guava

I am building a service that constantly receives packets of data and concatenates them based on packet group id. So I need a cache that can store similar packets together based on key and can expire the group key after a certain time to make space for new data. However I also need a guarantee that the cache does not expire the group before the expiry time. I have looked into guava cache and it says that it can evict keys even before max size is reached based on concurrency level and segment size. Since I am using multiple threads, I am concerned about this behavior. Is there a java based cache/concurrent-map that can suffice this requirement?

Comment: Are you planning on using a maximumSize constraint? If so then any cache would be allowed to evict prior to an entry expiring. If not then the expiration time dictates when the mapping is removed.

Comment: Have you tried something yet ? You could try Caffeine, it looks like it fit your requirements (see [this link](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Eviction#time-based)). I'm sure @BenManes would be able to provide more details. Another solution I see is using Spring Reactor to store values in a [GroupedFlux](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/), then [caching it using an expiry time](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#cache-java.time.Duration-reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler-).

Comment: If you're only evicting based on expiration time, not a maximum size, then Guava will do fine.